# Region function of rotated Polyhedron

Tags: regions, geometric-transform, polyhedra

Is it possible to find the equation of the internal region of a rotated polyhedron?  For example, the analytic region for a Dodecahedron is found by:

```
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z]
```

How does one find the equation of the same Dodecahedron rotated some angle about $x$, $y$ or $z$ axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[regF]
regF = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"];

regF[x, y, z] // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (2 x+z)+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\geq 0\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (2 x+z)\leq 5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land
>    \sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z\leq 5 \left(\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) y+\sqrt{5}+2\right)\land \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z\leq
>    2+\sqrt{5}\land \sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x+5 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) y+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z\leq 5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land 2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2
>    \sqrt{5}\right)} x+10 y\leq \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land 2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)} x\leq 10 y+\sqrt{10
>    \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land 5 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) y\leq \sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z+5
>    \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land z+\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{11}{8 \sqrt{5}}}\geq 0\land \sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x+5 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) y+\sqrt{10
>    \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\geq 0\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z\leq 2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)} x+5 \left(2
>    y+\sqrt{5}+2\right)\land 10 y+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} z\leq 2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)} x+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)$

```
ClearAll[rotate, rotatedRegF]

rotate[t_, axis : ("xaxis" | "yaxis" | "zaxis") : "xaxis"] := RotationTransform[t, 
  axis /. Thread[{"xaxis", "yaxis", "zaxis"} -> IdentityMatrix[3]]] @* List;

rotatedRegF[rf_, t_, axis : ("xaxis" | "yaxis" | "zaxis") : "xaxis"][x_, y_, z_] := 
   rf @@ rotate[t, axis][x, y, z]

rotatedRegF[regF, t][x, y, z] // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t)+2 x)+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\geq 0\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t)+2
>    x)\leq 5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t))+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x\leq 5 \left(\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) (y
>    \cos (t)-z \sin (t))+\sqrt{5}+2\right)\land \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t))\leq 2+\sqrt{5}\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y
>    \sin (t)+z \cos (t))+5 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x\leq 5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land 10 (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))+2
>    \sqrt{5 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)} x\leq \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t))+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land 2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2
>    \sqrt{5}\right)} x\leq \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t))+10 (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land 5
>    \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))\leq \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos (t))+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x+5
>    \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\land y \sin (t)+z \cos (t)+\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{11}{8 \sqrt{5}}}\geq 0\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin (t)+z \cos
>    (t))+5 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} x+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\geq 0\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin
>    (t)+z \cos (t))\leq 5 \left(2 (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))+\sqrt{5}+2\right)+2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)} x\land \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} (y \sin
>    (t)+z \cos (t))+10 (y \cos (t)-z \sin (t))\leq 2 \sqrt{5 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)} x+5 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)$

```
rfunctions = {"regF", "rotatedRegF[regF,Pi/2]",  "rotatedRegF[regF,Pi/2, \"yaxis\"]", 
  "rotatedRegF[regF,Pi/2, \"zaxis\"]"};

Grid[Partition[Labeled[RegionPlot3D[ToExpression[#][x, y, z],
     {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
      PlotPoints -> 40, ImageSize -> 300, 
      Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, Boxed -> False, 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}], #, Top] & /@ rfunctions, 2], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:** For interactive display, rendering the polyhedron once and using `GeometricTransformation` with desired transformation is faster:

```
ir = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "ImplicitRegion"];
rp = RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotPoints -> 70];

{xaxis, yaxis, zaxis} = IdentityMatrix[3];

Panel @ Manipulate[Row[Panel[
      Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[], 
         Cuboid[{-3, -3, -3}, {3, 3, 3}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
         Point[ctr]}, EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], 
        GeometricTransformation[rp[[1]], RotationTransform[t, #]]}, 
       Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300, 
       PlotLabel -> #]] & /@ {xaxis, yaxis, zaxis}], 
   {{t, 0}, -Pi, Pi}, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

Anchor rotation at, say, `vv = {2, 1, 1}`:

```
vv = {2, 1, 1};
centroid = {0.0000305046, -0.0000984894, -0.0000394806};

Manipulate[Row[Panel[
     Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[], 
        Cuboid[{-3, -3, -3}, {3, 3, 3}], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[vv]},
       Dashed, Thick, Opacity[1, Blue], 
       GeometricTransformation[Line[{centroid, vv}], RotationTransform[t, #, vv]], 
       EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], 
       GeometricTransformation[rp[[1]], RotationTransform[t, #, vv]]},
      Axes -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300, 
      PlotLabel -> #]] & /@ {xaxis, yaxis, zaxis}], 
   {{t, 0}, -Pi, Pi},  Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z] /. 
{x -> x Cos[\[Theta]] - y Sin[\[Theta]], 
 y -> y Cos[\[Theta]] + x Sin[\[Theta]]}
```

Comment: ...and if you want to apply a 3D rotation matrix, you could do something like `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> RollPitchYawMatrix[{π/5, -π/2, π}, {3, 2, 1}].{x, y, z}]`